# Magento2 - including THREE.js in custom module

Tags: magento2, php, javascript

I'm using a 3D model object in my Magento (2.4.0) site for which I need to use three.js lib along with GLTFLoader and OrbitControls. GLTFLoader and OrbitControls are THREE.js dependents. I kept the mentioned libs on below location.

```
app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/
```

Then I created requirejs-config.js file on below location

```
app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/
```

Here is the code for it

```
var config = {
    paths: {
       threejs: 'Vendor_Module/web/js/threejs.min',
       gltfloader: 'Vendor_Module/web/js/GLTFLoader',
       OrbitControls: 'Vendor_Module/web/js/OrbitControls',
    },
    shim: {
       threejs: {
           deps: ['jquery']
       },
       gltfloader: {
           deps: ['threejs']
       },
       OrbitControls: {
           deps: ['threejs']
       }
    }
};
```

On my phtml file I do it like

```
require(['jquery','threejs','gltfloader','OrbitControls'],function($,THREE,GLTFLoader,OrbitControls){
     var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
});
```

And I get these errors

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
at GLTFLoader.js:9
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my requirejs-config.js file like below

```
define('threejs', ['Vendor_Module/js/threejs'], function (THREE) {
   window.THREE = THREE;
   return THREE;
});
define('gltfloader', ['Vendor_Module/js/GLTFLoader'], function (gltfloader) {
   window.gltfloader = gltfloader;
   return gltfloader;
});
define('OrbitControls', ['Vendor_Module/js/OrbitControls'], function (OrbitControls) {
   window.OrbitControls = OrbitControls;
   return OrbitControls;
});
define('html2canvas', ['Vendor_Module/js/html2canvas'], function (html2canvas) {
   window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
   return html2canvas;
});
var config = {
paths:{
   threejs: 'Vendor_Module/js/threejs',
   gltfloader: 'Vendor_Module/js/GLTFLoader',
   OrbitControls: 'Vendor_Module/js/OrbitControls',
   html2Canvas: 'Vendor_Module/js/html2Canvas',
},
shim: {
    'Vendor_Module/js/GLTFLoader': {
        deps: ['threejs']
    },
    'Vendor_Module/js/OrbitControls': {
        deps: ['threejs']
    }
 }
});
```

And then I ran this command

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

And then in my phtml file I included those files as

```
require(['threejs','gltfloader','OrbitControls','html2canvas'],function(THREE,GLTFLoader,OrbitControls,html2canvas){
});
```

Everything worked fine as I wanted.

Comment: Thanks. It's worked with new ThreeJs versions